# post an item in SharePoint list gives 400 Bad request

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, api

I have been 3 days trying to get items in text filed transfer into SharePoint list to work but now i have a 400 bad request error in the console.

This is my code:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function createListItem() {
        //Fetch the values from the input elements  
        var eName = $('#title').val();  
        var eDesg = $('#name').val();  
        var eEmail = $('#email').val();  
        var eMobile = $('#moblie').val();  
        var eResidency = $('#Residency').val();  
        var eRequestDetails = $('#RequestDetails').val();  
        var eStatus = $('#Status').val(); 
        //alert(fullName);
        //alert(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ExitPermitRequest')/items");
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "http://stag.psa.gov.qa/en/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ndsList')/items",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Data.ndsListListItem' // it defines the ListEnitityTypeName  
                },
                'Title': eName,
                'Full_x0020_Name': eDesg,
                'Moblile_x0020_Phone': eMobile,
                'E-Mail': eEmail,
                'Residency': Residency,
                'RequestDetails': eRequestDetails,
                'Status': eStatus
            }),
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the Data format   
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the content type as JSON  
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() //It gets the digest value   
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Item created successfully", "success"); // Used sweet alert for success message  
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("error occured"+ error);
            }
        })
    }


  </script>
```

```html
<div id="insert1">  
        <table>  
            <tr>  
                <td> Title: </td>  
                <td>  
                    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" /> </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td> Full Name: </td>  
                <td>  
                    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" /> </td>  
            </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td> Email: </td>  
                <td>  
                    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" /> </td>  
            </tr> 
            <tr>  
                <td> Moblie Number: </td>  
                <td>  
                    <input type="text" id="moblie" placeholder="Moblie Number" /> </td>  
            </tr>
          <tr>
                   <td> Residency: </td>
          <td><select id="Residency">
            <option selected>In Qatar</option>
            <option>Outside Qatar</option>
          </select></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td> RequestDetails: </td>
                <td>  
                    <input type="text" id="RequestDetails" placeholder="RequestDetails" /> </td>  
            </tr> 
                <tr>
                   <td> Status: </td>
          <td><select id="Status">
            <option selected>Not Started</option>
            <option>In Progress</option>
            <option>Pending</option>
            <option>Completed</option>
          </select></td>
          </tr>
            <tr>  
                <td></td>  
                <td>  
                    <button onclick="createListItem()">Click me</button>
                </td>  
            </tr>  
        </table>  
    </div>
```

I tried to input the data as hard coded but I didn't worked.
I don't know where is my problem ,also is *x0020* right if SharePoint column have a space?

Answer (score 0):

The 400 bad request error may be caused if you/the user is part of too many Active Directory groups

To resolve this there are two recommended solutions given by Microsoft. The first is to delete surplus Active Directory groups, the second is to configure registry settings and then restart your server.

From [source:](http://www.softvative.com/blog/2015/11/sharepoint-http-400-bad-request-error/)

> There are two options. Either remove extra AD groups from the user’s
>   AD account or configure the registry settings on IIS (Internet
>   Information Server) web servers.
>
> Registry location on IIS web servers:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters
>
> Set values for MaxFieldLength and MaxRequestBytes registry keys.
>
> Name              Value-Type    Value-Data
>
> MaxFieldLength   DWORD        65534
>
> MaxRequestBytes   DWORD        16777216